# How to colour branch/edge on a tree using tikz?

Tags: tikz-trees, trees

[image]

I have created a tree diagram using `tikz` on Latex. However I'm not sure how to go about highlighting/adding colour to a branch. For instance, looking at the tree that I've illustrated, I want to highlight(in red) the edges of the path from `343` to `357` to `357` to `z = 375`. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape] {article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,calc,shapes,backgrounds}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}



\tikzset{
treenode/.style = {align=center, inner sep=0pt, text centered,
    font=\sffamily},
arn/.style = {treenode, circle, black, font=\sffamily\bfseries, draw=black,
    fill=white, text width=4.1ex},
arnrec/.style = {treenode, rectangle, black, font=\sffamily\bfseries, draw=black,
    fill=white, text width=7.5ex,minimum width=4.0ex, minimum height=4.0ex},
arnsmall/.style = {treenode, circle, black, font=\sffamily\bfseries, draw=black,
    fill=white, text width=1.5ex},
}

\begin{document}
\centering
\tiny %font size
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,scale=0.85]
\node [sibling distance=10mm,level distance = 0.5cm] [arn] {start} 
 child{[sibling distance=2.8cm,level distance = 1.5cm] node [arn] {343}
            child{ [sibling distance=0.8cm] node [arn] {343} 
                        child{[level distance=0.6cm]node [arn] {367} 
                                child{node [arnsmall] {f}}
                        edge from parent node[above left]{$x_{32}$}
                        } 
                        child{[level distance=0.6cm] node [arn] {384}
                                child{node [arnsmall] {f}}
                        edge from parent node[above] {$x_{35}$}
                        }
                        child{ [level distance = 0.6cm] node [arn] {376}
                                child{node [arnsmall] {f}}
                        edge from parent node[above right]
                        {$x_{36}$}
                        }
                edge from parent node[above left]
                {$x_{21}$} %label
            }
            child{ [sibling distance=0.8cm] node [arn] {357} 
                        child{ [level distance = 0.6cm] node [arn] {386} 
                                child{node [arnsmall] {f}}
                                edge from parent node[above left] {$x_{31}$}
                        }
                        child{[level distance=0.6cm] node [arn] {389}
                                child{node [arnsmall] {f}}
                            edge from parent node[above] {$x_{35}$}
                        }
                        child{[sibling distance=0.7cm,level distance = 1.4cm] node [arn] {357} 
                                child{ node [arnrec] {z=396}
                                    edge from parent node[below left]
                                    {$x_{42}$}
                                }   
                                child{ node [arnrec] {z=375}
                                    edge from parent node[below right]
                                    {$x_{45}$}
                                }
                            edge from parent node[above right] {$x_{36}$}
                        }
            edge from parent node[above left]
            {$x_{23}$} %label
            }                         
    edge from parent node[above right]
    {$x_{14}$} %label
    }
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You should be using `forest` for better (wait for cfr to add an example, for sure `:-)`). For your code, you have to add few `red` and `black` at suitable places.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape] {article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,calc,shapes,backgrounds}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}



\tikzset{
treenode/.style = {align=center, inner sep=0pt, text centered,
    font=\sffamily},
arn/.style = {treenode, circle, black, font=\sffamily\bfseries, draw=black,
    fill=white, text width=4.1ex},
arnrec/.style = {treenode, rectangle, black, font=\sffamily\bfseries, draw=black,
    fill=white, text width=7.5ex,minimum width=4.0ex, minimum height=4.0ex},
arnsmall/.style = {treenode, circle, black, font=\sffamily\bfseries, draw=black,
    fill=white, text width=1.5ex},
}

\begin{document}
\centering
\tiny %font size
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,scale=0.85]
\node [sibling distance=10mm,level distance = 0.5cm] [arn] {start}
 child{[sibling distance=2.8cm,level distance = 1.5cm] node [arn] {343}
            child{ [sibling distance=0.8cm] node [arn] {343}
                        child{[level distance=0.6cm]node [arn] {367}
                                child{node [arnsmall] {f}}
                        edge from parent node[above left]{$x_{32}$}
                        }
                        child{[level distance=0.6cm] node [arn] {384}
                                child{node [arnsmall] {f}}
                        edge from parent node[above] {$x_{35}$}
                        }
                        child{ [level distance = 0.6cm] node [arn] {376}
                                child{node [arnsmall] {f}}
                        edge from parent node[above right]
                        {$x_{36}$}
                        }
                edge from parent node[above left]
                {$x_{21}$} %label
            }
            child{ [sibling distance=0.8cm,red] node [arn] {357}
                        child{ [level distance = 0.6cm,black] node [arn] {386}
                                child{node [arnsmall] {f}}
                                edge from parent node[above left] {$x_{31}$}
                        }
                        child{[level distance=0.6cm,black] node [arn] {389}
                                child{node [arnsmall] {f}}
                            edge from parent node[above] {$x_{35}$}
                        }
                        child{[sibling distance=0.7cm,level distance = 1.4cm,red] node [arn] {357}
                                child{[black] node[arnrec] {z=396}
                                    edge from parent node[below left]
                                    {$x_{42}$}
                                }
                                child{ node [arnrec] {z=375}
                                    edge from parent node[below right]
                                    {$x_{45}$}
                                }
                            edge from parent node[above right] {$x_{36}$}
                        }
            edge from parent node[above left]
            {$x_{23}$} %label
            }
    edge from parent node[above right]
    {$x_{14}$} %label
    }
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm new to latex and tikz, hence the long, messy code:)

Comment: @alex12 Harish Kumar knows me too well, it seems ;). Did you want the labels to be red, as well? You only mentioned the edges, so I did something to stop the labels being red. But I can undo it if you want them red. Your code is not that long or messy. It is really good if you are new to it. (IMHO.) But `forest` allows trees to be specified with really concise code.

Comment: @cfr I know your love for `forest` ;-)

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing to use `forest`, this can be done fairly simply, the code can be simplified and some nodes can be created automatically. In this case, I've appended the `f` nodes automatically. I've created a style `my x` to make it easier to add the edge labels, and I've used a `tier`, in combination with 2 `phantom` nodes to manage the alignment of the terminal nodes.

This could probably be further automated and could certainly be further fine-tuned if you've a mind.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi] {standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\standaloneenv{forest,tikzpicture}

\tikzset{
  treenode/.style = {align=center, inner sep=0pt, text centered, font=\sffamily},
  arn/.style = {treenode, circle, font=\sffamily\bfseries, draw=black, fill=white, text width=4.75ex},
  arnrec/.style = {treenode, rectangle, font=\sffamily\bfseries, draw=black,  fill=white, text width=7.5ex,minimum width=4.0ex, minimum height=4.0ex},
  arnsmall/.style = {treenode, circle, font=\sffamily\bfseries, draw=black, fill=white, text width=1.5ex},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  make f/.style={
    append={[f, arnsmall, tier=prez]},
    l sep+=-5mm,
  },
  make empty/.style={
    coordinate,
    no edge,
    tier=prez,
    for children={
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!uu.parent anchor) -- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
      }
    },
  },
  my x/.style n args=2{
    edge label={node [midway, #2, font=\sffamily, text=black] {$x_{#1}$}},
  },
  for tree={
    arn,
    l sep+=5mm,
  }
  [start
    [343, my x={14}{right}
      [343, for children={make f}, my x={21}{left}
        [367, my x={32}{left}
        ]
        [384, my x={35}{fill=white}
        ]
        [376, my x={36}{right}
        ]
      ]
      [357, my x={23}{right}
        [386, make f, my x={31}{left}
        ]
        [389, make f, my x={35}{fill=white}
        ]
        [357, my x={36}{right}
          [, make empty
            [{z=396}, arnrec, my x={42}{left, pos=.75}]
          ]
          [, make empty
            [{z=375}, arnrec, for ancestors={edge=red}, edge=red, my x={45}{right, pos=.75}]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: <code>forest</code> solution]

If you don't want the edge from `start` to the first child to be red, delete `for ancestors={edge=red}` and just add two `edge=red` to the two `357` nodes instead:

```
  [start
    [343, my x={14}{right}
      [343, for children={make f}, my x={21}{left}
        [367, my x={32}{left}
        ]
        [384, my x={35}{fill=white}
        ]
        [376, my x={36}{right}
        ]
      ]
      [357, my x={23}{right}, edge=red
        [386, make f, my x={31}{left}
        ]
        [389, make f, my x={35}{fill=white}
        ]
        [357, my x={36}{right}, edge=red
          [, make empty
            [{z=396}, arnrec, my x={42}{left, pos=.75}]
          ]
          [, make empty
            [{z=375}, arnrec, edge=red, my x={45}{right, pos=.75}]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

[image: per instructions]

It is just that the `for ancestors` is so neat that I couldn't resist demonstrating it ;).